# OAuth2 from Android to my Django API requires to go to /accounts/login

Tags: java, android, python, django, oauth

So I was trying to implement a feature on my android app where users can register and login to the app. I made it where the user credentials are stored to an external and can be validated with the Django REST API I made.

So before I can let my app access that API page, I have to make sure it goes with OAuth2 rules. However, it requires me to login to an `/accounts/login` page. Do I need to make that page or can I change the url if don't want that path or maybe not login as admin at all?

It keeps me wanting to login before I can authorize my app.

login.java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button LoginButton, RegButton;
    EditText uUserName, uPassWord;
    WSAdapter.SendAPIRequests AuthHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //SetupHomeBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.SetupHomeBtn);

        LoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LoginButton);
        RegButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LoginRegister);

        uUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LoginUserBox);
        uPassWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LoginPassBox);

        //AuthHelper = new WSAdapter().new SendDeviceDetails();

        // Moves user to the main page after validation
        LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // gets the username and password from the EditText
                String strUserName = uUserName.getText().toString();
                String strPassWord = uPassWord.getText().toString();

                //startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Posts.class));

                // To authorize oauth for requesting access token
                OAuthClientRequest request = null;

                try {
                    // sends authorization request with credentials to the server
                    request = OAuthClientRequest
                            .authorizationLocation("http://192.168.0.18:8000/auth/authorize")
                            .setClientId("mNUNXI4MinYyVvsRi1VPiv7ltrZWBOzr3OfnHJa1").setRedirectURI("http://oauthresponse")
                            .buildQueryMessage();
                } catch (OAuthSystemException e) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "OAuth request failed", e);
                }

                // authentication service requires &reponse_type=code
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse(request.getLocationUri() + "&response_type=code"));
                startActivity(intent);

                // API url duh
                String APIUrl = "http://192.168.0.18:8000/token-auth/";

                // If the user is authenticated, then transfer to the MainActivity page
                if (APIAuthentication(strUserName, strPassWord, APIUrl)){
                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Posts.class));
                }
            }
        });


        RegButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // gets the username and password from the EditText
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Register.class));
            }
        });

    }

    // to handle authorization for the redirect_url
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Uri uri = intent.getData();

        if (uri != null && uri.toString()
                .startsWith("http://oauthresponse"))
        {
            String code = uri.getQueryParameter("code");
        }
    }

    private boolean APIAuthentication(String un, String pw, String url){
        // when it wasn't static -> AuthHelper = new WSAdapter().new SendAPIRequests();
        AuthHelper = new WSAdapter.SendAPIRequests();

        JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();
        try {
            // Attempt to input info to the Django API
            postData.put("username", un);
            postData.put("password", pw);

            // Putting the data to be posted in the Django API
            //AuthHelper.execute(url, postData.toString());

            return true;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```